# Get the removed and added elements from a string arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a String arraylist `ListA` containing values, say `{a,b,c,d}`. I did some operations and the `ListA` now contains, say, `{b,c,e}`

I have to find out what all elements have been removed from `ListA` i.e `a` and `d` and what all elements have been added i.e `e`.

Please help. I am new to Java and am stuck with this.

Comment: Make a temp `ArrayList` which contains the old values and compare its values to the new created `ArrayList`.

Comment: your ArrayList instance would just contain a snapshot, for comparison you need a reference point.

Comment: 1. iterate over your initial list and check every single item whether your result list `contains` ist -> if not it has been removed. 2. now iterate ofer your result list and check if your initial list `contains` the items -> the once not present have been added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use temporary ArrayList which is your initial arraylist before any modifications.

Then you need to do loop with a new arraylist and compare and extract and blah... blah..

It can be done using programmatic only. No any direct way to find this.

---

See update

```
public class ListTracAddedAndRemoved {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<String> old = new ArrayList<String>();
old.add("a");
old.add("b");
old.add("c");

ArrayList<String> newOne = new ArrayList<String>();
newOne.add("b");
newOne.add("d");
newOne.add("e");

ArrayList<String> removed = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String oldString : old) {
    if(!newOne.contains(oldString)){
    removed.add(oldString);
    }
}

ArrayList<String> newAdded = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String newString : newOne) {
    if(!old.contains(newString)){
    newAdded.add(newString);
    }
}

System.out.println("Removed: "+removed.toString());
System.out.println("NewAdded: "+newAdded.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: "No any direct way to find this." unless the op plans to subclass the used list class and override the `add` and `remove` methods to keep track of the items that have been added or removed

Comment: Thanks Ketan. I would be thankful if you could please tell me the logic for doing that. If i am not wrong, we will have to use nested for loops. Stuck on the logic inside the for loops.

Comment: @ketan: i am able to retreive the newAdded but not the removed ones. Please help.

Comment: @user2358066 It should work as per above example, I have been given.

Comment: Thanks Ketan. It worked fine. It was a silly mistake from my side. :)

Comment: @user2358066 Your welcome and can you select your desired answer and close this question...

Answer (score 4):

you actually have 3 options what i could suggest.

1. have a referenceList from which you can compare the ListA after modification, so that you can list out added/removed elements.

   > > see Noob UnChained's answer for sample code.
2. instead of using `Arraylist`, extend it and override `remove()` & Noob UnChained methods to add(make sure you persist a call to super() just in case) logic to store elements being removed/added.

   > > see Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer for sample code.
3. instead of directly calling `add()/remove()` Write utility methods which will in turn call `add()/remove()` along with storing that element to `add()/remove()` from corresponding `addedList` & `removedList`

Answer (score 1):

Sample code, which you can use to carve out a better solution:

```
// your initial list
List<String> oldList = new ArrayList<String>();
// new List , which you will manipulate
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(oldList);

// add , remove elements from the newList

for(String element:oldList){
    if(!newList.contains(element)){
        System.out.println("New list has removed :"+element);
    }
}

for(String element:newList){
    if(!oldList.contains(element)){
        System.out.println("New list has added :"+element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noob Unchained. The added elements are retrievable. However,the removed elements are not being printed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom version of List like this

```
class TestList implements List {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    List added = new ArrayList();
    List removed = new ArrayList();
    public void add(int index, Object element) {
        added.add(e);
        list.add(index, element);
    }
    public Object remove(int index) {
        removed.add(get(index));
        return list.remove(index);
    }
    ...
    public List getAdded() {
        return added;
    }
    public List getRemoved() {
        return removed;
    }
```